# Lifting section coherent sheaf restriction on $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a rank $n$ sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ given as the image of a square matrix with linear entries of size $> 2n$. In particular, we have two exact sequences:
$$ V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(-1) \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow 0,$$
and
$$ 0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{F} \longrightarrow V \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n},$$
where $\dim V > 2n$.
Assume that for generic $\mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^n$, we have $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} = \mathcal{O}(-1)^{\oplus p} \oplus \mathcal{O}^{\oplus q}$, with $q \geq 1$ (in particular, the non-locally free locus of $\mathcal{F}$ has codimension larger than $2$). Do we necessarily have $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{F}) \neq 0$?

Note that $H^n(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{F}) = 0$ (by the above surjection) and the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch Theorem allows to answer positively to my question in case $n \leq 2$. But for $n \geq 3$, there are higher positive terms in $\chi(\mathbb{P}^n, \mathcal{F})$ and I am not sure if the result is still true.